# How to display images in the list action of rails_admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I have a self-associating model which allows the user to define a "parent photo", in order to group them together.

My model:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :image, :parent_photo

  has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }

  validates_attachment :image, 
    :presence => true,
    :size => { :in => 20..2000.kilobytes },
    :content_type => { :content_type => [ 'image/jpeg', 'image/png' ] }

  belongs_to :parent, class_name: "Photo", foreign_key: :parent_photo

  def associated_photos
    Photo.find_by_parent_photo(id)
  end

end
```

And in my rails_admin initializer:

```
..

  config.model Photo do

    list do
      field :image
      field :associated_photos     
    end
  end
end
```

How do I retrieve the actual thumbnail for use in the list action?

Answer (score 9):

It seems like this is addressed on [the wiki](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Railsadmin-DSL) under the heading "Fields - Output formatting."

Will something like this work?

```
config.model Photo do
  list do
    field :image do
      formatted_value do
        bindings[:view].tag(:img, { :src => bindings[:object].image.url }) << value
      end
    field :associated_photos     
  end
end
```

Comment: This worked for me (using just `.image` instead of `.image.url`). Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

To show the image field:

```
config.model Photo do
  list do
    field :image do
      pretty_value do
        bindings[:view].tag(:img, { :src => bindings[:object].image.url(:thumb) })
      end
    end
  end
end
```